# tf.assign() - How to Increment value by given value in each iteration

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create iteration in tensor flow where "val" increases by one after each iteration of the loop below. But this code increases it by 2. so i have two questions:

1.) Why is it happening?
2.) what should i do to make it add only 1 in each iteration?

```
iters = 10

x = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
val = tf.Variable(y-x, name="val")
assign_op = tf.assign(val, val+1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print("val_init",val.eval())

    for iter in range(iters):
        sess.run(assign_op)
        print(iter, x.eval(),y.eval(),"val",val.eval(),"assign_op", assign_op.eval())
```

## RESULTS:

```
"""
val_init 1.0
0 1.0 2.0 val 2.0 assign_op 3.0
1 1.0 2.0 val 4.0 assign_op 5.0
2 1.0 2.0 val 6.0 assign_op 7.0
3 1.0 2.0 val 8.0 assign_op 9.0
4 1.0 2.0 val 10.0 assign_op 11.0
5 1.0 2.0 val 12.0 assign_op 13.0
6 1.0 2.0 val 14.0 assign_op 15.0
7 1.0 2.0 val 16.0 assign_op 17.0
8 1.0 2.0 val 18.0 assign_op 19.0
9 1.0 2.0 val 20.0 assign_op 21.0
"""
```

Comment: after @sladomic answer i modified the code to following:

    for iter in range(iters):
        val_pre = val.eval() # new variable captures current state of "val"; must be placed before .run() and needs to .eval() the variable 
        sess.run(assign_op)
        # print(epoch, assign_op", assign_op.eval()) # this will cause "assign_op" to execute again!!!
        print(iter,"val PRE:",val_pre, "val AFTER:",val.eval())

Answer (score 1):

Your "assign_op.eval()" is increasing "val" as well. So you are increasing it twice per iteration. You see it in your output.

""" val_init **1.0** 0 1.0 2.0 val **2.0** assign_op **3.0** 1 1.0 2.0 val **4.0** assign_op **5.0** 2 1.0 2.0 val **6.0** assign_op **7.0** 3 1.0 2.0 val **8.0** assign_op **9.0** 4 1.0 2.0 val **10.0** assign_op **11.0** 5 1.0 2.0 val **12.0** assign_op **13.0** 6 1.0 2.0 val **14.0** assign_op **15.0** 7 1.0 2.0 val **16.0** assign_op **17.0** 8 1.0 2.0 val **18.0** assign_op **19.0** 9 1.0 2.0 val **20.0** assign_op **21.0** """